# What type should I use for the number of bits in a fundamental type?

Tags: c++, bit, idioms

[Fundamental types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) in C++ have sizes between 1 and 8 (perhaps 16), on 64-bits operating systems. That means the number of bits they take up in memory is no higher than 128, i.e. the number of bits fits in an `uint8_t`.

Now, suppose I write some function which takes such a number of bits. For example, suppose it's

```
template <typename T>
inline void clear_bit(T& x, magic_type bit_index ) {
    static_assert(std::is_fundamental_v<T>, "Go away.");
    x = x & ~(T{1} << bit_index);
}
```

I'm wondering what to use for `magic_type`: Should it be a `uint8_t`? Or maybe it should be just be an int, since I would need to check for validity anyway, even for  a `uint8_t` case, and with `int` being a more "natural" type for numbers?

To make this question less about your individual opinion: Is one of the options generally considered more idiomatic? If not, can you find good enough reasons for both choices? Or perhaps suggest a third one?

Comment: How future proof do you want the code to be?  When the i25 1024bit processor comes out do you still want the code to work?

Comment: Consider this: what would happen if you wanted to have a similar `clear_bit` function as a member of some bit-array class? Or what if you wanted a generic `clear_bit` that could function on any arbitrary bit-range concept? That's the type you should use.

Comment: I'm not sure what's best but if you match the operating type `T` then I assume you won't lose anything given that it will likely get promoted to that for the math?

Comment: I believe LEWG settled on `int` for the proposed rotation functions.

Comment: @T.C. That's seems like an odd choice `int` given that bit operations are generally recommended to only be done on unsigned types.

Comment: @galik I believe that the discussion is around the type of `bit_index`, not `x`.

Comment: @Galik The source type is constrained to be unsigned, but the rotation count is `int`.

Comment: @paddy Yes but isn't mixing signed and unsigned generally thought to be bad?

Comment: My controversial side is telling me that most compilers would not care about the use of `int`, since it's kinda _the_ fundamental type.  Even though left-shifting by a negative is undefined behavior.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I wouldn't mind some future-proofness, but I'm more interested in conforming to current social norms. I want to follow the herd on this... :-)

Comment: @NicolBolas: But I'm talking about something that's specifically _not_ extensible.

Comment: @T.C.: So are you telling me to go with an int?

Comment: I like size_t for stuff like this, even though it isn't exactly what it is designed for.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever type you use for `bit_index` in the expression `T{1} << bit_index`, it will be promoted to `int` or `unsigned int` in  any case and the result of `T{1} << bit_index` itself is the promoted type of `T{1}`. This means that `x & ~(T{1} << bit_index)` always yield a type that is at least 'as large as' an `int`.

The expression `T{1} << bit_index` is well defined only if 
`bit_index >= 0 && bit_index < (sizeof +T{}) * CHAR_BIT)`. The subsequent assignment to `x` may still truncate the result.

As a rule of thumb, if you intend to use a variable in arithmetic expressions, use `int` or `unsigned int`. `unsigned` is usually preferable in bitwise arithmetic contexts, otherwise just use `signed`.

**Bottom line**: Use `unsigned int`, or possibly `signed int`.